# Self adjoint map and the existence of real eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

Say $T:V\to V$ and $V$ a finite dimensional vector space. I know that if $T$ is self adjoint and if $T$ has a eigenvalue then it must be real. Is it true that $T$ always have a real eigenvalue then? What if I lift of the assumption that $V$ is finite dimensional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $T$ is self adjoint then  all eigen values are real.

In the infinite dimensional case the entire specrtum is contained in the real line. In particular eigen values, if any, are real.